# Nutch - Crawler not following next pages in paginated content

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I'm using nutch 1.6 to crawl a paginated web page containing 20 products/page, with this command:

`./nutch crawl urls -dir <dir> -depth 4 -topN 100 -threads 100`

I'm getting the 20 first products & the links to the following pages. But the crawler is not following my next pages link? Am I missing a parameter?

Comment: Are the paginated links direct hyper links ?? or AJax or other form ?

Comment: They are just `a` html tags, not Ajax links.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Nutch 1.6 lacks the support for crawling Ajax based sites. See [this](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/How-to-crowl-AJAX-populated-pages-td3783398.html) and [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1323). There are no immediate plans to add the same.

Comment: I know that Nutch doesnt support Ajax. But, the pagination isn't made with Ajax. Maybe the command I'm launching isnt correct. Here is the url (urls/seed.txt) Im trying to crawl: [Ouedkniss](http://www.ouedkniss.com/fr/annonces/categorie.php?c=informatique)

Answer (score 0):

The regex-urlfilter blocks urls that have querystring parameters:

# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.

-[?*!@=]

Modify that file so that urls with querystring parameters are crawled:

# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.

-[*!@]

Comment: Do the meta tags allow crawling, i.e. are they blocked by robots.txt or the <meta name="robots"> tag on the page? does the <a> tag have a rel=nofollow or noindex?

Comment: There no `rel=nofollow` in `<a>` tags, the `<meta>` robot's tag has an `index, follow` content attribute, and I dont think that it's blocked by text file. Maybe the issue is in the command I'm typing?

Comment: Your command will crawl pages four levels deep, maximum of 100 pages per level. Maybe you could try increasing those limits to see if your pages get crawled.

Comment: I understand that. I think that I need to increase the depth.